# Substituting first row by last row and so on in a matrix using MATLAB or Excel

Tags: excel, matlab, matrix

I have a 16*20 [input] matrix (**A**). I want to have a 16*20 output matrix (**B**) such that:

**A**1,1 = **B**16,20,
**A**1,2 = **B**16,19,
**A**1,3 = **B**16,18, …,
**A**2,1 = **B**15,20,
**A**2,2 = **B**15,19,
**A**2,3 = **B**15,18  and so on.

What should I do in MS Excel or MATLAB?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You could maybe try it yourself first?

Comment: I'm having a hard time reading your syntax.  Could you perhaps show us in a table or something a little more pleasing to the human eye instead?

Comment: Are you just rotating the matrix 180 degrees?

Comment: Both Matlab and Exel can handle it - this is a very simple problem. It will be better to provide example with less number of rows and columns, and after that adopt the answer to your own problem

Comment: @beaker - It looks like a rotation yes.  The user can simply call `rot90` twice: `B = rot90(A, 2);`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to rotate the matrix 180 degrees.  Calling [`rot90`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rot90.html) twice to rotate the matrix 180 degrees should do what you want:

```
B = rot90(A, 2);
```

## Example

```
>> A = reshape(1:25,5,5)

A =

     1     6    11    16    21
     2     7    12    17    22
     3     8    13    18    23
     4     9    14    19    24
     5    10    15    20    25

>> B = rot90(A,2)

B =

    25    20    15    10     5
    24    19    14     9     4
    23    18    13     8     3
    22    17    12     7     2
    21    16    11     6     1
```

---

An alternative if you don't like `rot90` is to call [`fliplr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fliplr.html) then [`flipud`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fliplr.html).  The effect is that every row is flipped from left to right and every column is flipped from up to down.  It doesn't matter what order you put them in.

## Example

```
>> A = reshape(1:25,5,5)

A =

     1     6    11    16    21
     2     7    12    17    22
     3     8    13    18    23
     4     9    14    19    24
     5    10    15    20    25

>> B = fliplr(flipud(A))

B =

    25    20    15    10     5
    24    19    14     9     4
    23    18    13     8     3
    22    17    12     7     2
    21    16    11     6     1
```

Answer (score 0):

With just a small code, you can visually the transformation that you want:

```
R = 16; 
C = 20; 
A = cell(R, C); 
for r = 1:R, 
  for c = 1:C, 
    A(r,c) = strcat(num2str(r),',',num2str(c)); 
  end, 
end

B = flipud(fliplr(A))
```